# HardHat error: Invalid number of arguments error for constructor with no passed arguments

Tags: solidity, nft, hardhat

When ever I run npx hardhat test I get this Error: missing argument:  in Contract constructor (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)

here is the main contract:

```
 contract KBMarket is ReentrancyGuard {

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    address payable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
```

and here is hardhat test.js:

```
describe("KBMarket", function () {
  it("Should Mint And Trade NFTs", async function () {
    const Market = await ethers.getContractFactory('KBMarket')
    const market = await Market.deploy()
    await market.deployed()
    const marketAddress = market.adderss
  }
}
```

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: This is odd - have you tried deleting your cache and artifacts directories?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo, is address instead of adderss